# Evaluation with dplyr::select does not work in my function

Tags: r, dplyr, evaluation, tidyselect

I am really new on dealing with evaluation issues in R.

```
example<- data.frame(id = 1:5,
                 pairs0 = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2),
                 pairs1 = c(2, 2, 1, 1, 1)
                     )
```

Here is the function that I am trying to write:

```
f <- function(df, col_pair){
       
       df2 <- df %>% mutate(j = row_number())

full_join(df2 %>% select(j, col_pair),
          df2 %>% select(j, col_pair),
          suffix = c('1', '2'),
          by = "{{col_pair}}",
          keep = TRUE) %>%
filter(j1 != j2)
}
```

The function picks a data frame `df` and joins it to itself by column `col_pair`.
The thing is, if I run `f(example, pairs0)`, I get that "join columns must be present in data"

Can someone help?

Comment: It looks like you're mixing `merge` options in there, `all.x` is not an argument to `dplyr::left_join` (though it produces no warnings/errors when included).

Comment: Where do you try to use any `tidyselect` logic?

Comment: @r2evans sorry, I meant that I was in doubt whether I should use stuff like ```{{col_pair}}``` instead

Comment: You can do this by using `{{col_pair}}` within your function; but with your last `filter` operation you don't get any rows back

Comment: @starja Now I've noticed a mistake in my function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have made a modification to your function, you can see as an option because it uses the variable with quotes and it can be less troublesome as using other evaluation schemes. Here the code:

```
#Function
f <- function(df, col_pair){
  
  df2 <- df %>% mutate(j = row_number())
  
  full_join(df2 %>% select(j, col_pair),
            df2 %>% select(j, col_pair),
            suffix = c('1', '2'),
            by = col_pair,
            keep = TRUE) %>%
    filter(j1 != j2)
}
#Apply
f(example, 'pairs0')
```

Output:

```
  j1 pairs01 j2 pairs02
1  1       1  2       1
2  1       1  3       1
3  2       1  1       1
4  2       1  3       1
5  3       1  1       1
6  3       1  2       1
7  4       2  5       2
8  5       2  4       2
```

Also, if non standard evaluation is needed you can use this:

```
#Option 2
f <- function(df, col_pair){
  
  var <- enquo(col_pair)
  
  df2 <- df %>% mutate(j = row_number())
  
  full_join(df2 %>% select(j, !!var),
            df2 %>% select(j, !!var),
            suffix = c('1', '2'),
            by = rlang::as_name(var),
            keep = TRUE) %>%
    filter(j1 != j2)
}
```

We apply:

```
#Apply
f(example, pairs0)
```

Output:

```
  j1 pairs01 j2 pairs02
1  1       1  2       1
2  1       1  3       1
3  2       1  1       1
4  2       1  3       1
5  3       1  1       1
6  3       1  2       1
7  4       2  5       2
8  5       2  4       2
```

Comment: Thank you! Could you please take a look in the updated question? I want to join only on the ```col_pair``` column, so that I have trouble when dealing with the ```by``` argument in ```full_join```

Comment: @Duck do you mean `enquo` and `!!` with new evaluation standard? Reading [how to program with `dplyr`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html), I thought `{{}}` is the new kid in town?

Comment: @starja Yeah both are as the new kids of town for functions in `dplyr` at least that is what I have seen. Sorry if I was wrong and I confused you!

Comment: @ArthurCarvalhoBrito I have added an update for what you want, maybe it be helpful for you!

Comment: @Duck thank you! Just one more thing, I get this message after running the real function that applies your solution: ```Using an external vector in selections is ambiguous.
i Use `all_of(col_pair)` instead of `col_pair` to silence this message.``` Should I actually follow this ? Where should the replacements be?

Comment: @ArthurCarvalhoBrito It is a warning. It makes reference that new functions from dplyr can do the task. Try changing the `by=col_pair` section with `by = all_of(col_pair)`. Results are the same. I have tested it :)

Comment: @ArthurCarvalhoBrito Also, I have dived deep and added another version of your function using non standard evaluation, this means no quotes. So you can have two options if needed. Same outputs!